# Change the font used by ImageString

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php 

//Other part of code


Header("Content-type: image/png");  
$im = imagecreatefromPng("./images/signatures/background.png");  


$red = ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 0, 0); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 


ImageString($im, 5, 15, 5, "$callsign", $black); 
ImageString($im, 5, 15, 20, "$name $surname", $black); 
ImageString($im, 5, 15, 35, "Location: $location", $black); 
ImageString($im, 5, 15, 50, "HUB: $hub", $black); 
ImageString($im, 5, 15, 65, "Hours: $hours", $black); 


$font_width = ImageFontWidth(5);  

ImagePng($im);  
?>
```

I want to change the font that PHP uses to write in the image. How can i do that?? I try but I can´t.

Comment: You mean you want to change the *font*?

Comment: *I want to change the type of letter*? Font face? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What do you mean by changing type? Changing font?

Comment: Type means what, font or something else?

Comment: I want to change font type!! Like Arial!

Answer (score 2):

You can use  imageloadfont ();

syntax:

```
 int imageloadfont ( string $file )
```

Example:

```
// Create a new image instance
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 20);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

// Make the background white
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 49, 19, $white);

// Load the gd font and write 'Hello'
$font = imageloadfont('./04b.gdf');
imagestring($im, $font, 0, 0, 'Hello', $black);

// Output to browser
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

**so change your code to:**

```
//Other part of code


Header("Content-type: image/png");  
$im = imagecreatefromPng("./images/signatures/background.png");  
$font = imageloadfont('./fonts/arial.gdf');//change the parameter based on your font file name

$red = ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 0, 0); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 


ImageString($im, $font, 15, 5, "$callsign", $black); 
ImageString($im, $font, 15, 20, "$name $surname", $black); 
ImageString($im, $font, 15, 35, "Location: $location", $black); 
ImageString($im, $font, 15, 50, "HUB: $hub", $black); 
ImageString($im, $font, 15, 65, "Hours: $hours", $black); 


$font_width = ImageFontWidth(5);  

ImagePng($im);
```

Comment: Ok, but How Can aplly that to my code?? My font is in ./fonts/arial.ttf or ./fonts/arial.gdf

Comment: Now I have other problem. The font size is really big and where I need to put imageloadfont ( string $file )

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean font:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php this may help if your using ttf fonts