# Change fonts in convering text to image in php

Tags: php, image, text, watermark

I want to change font in following code...

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$text = $_POST['wtr'];
$font = 'fonts/arial.ttf';
$im = @imagecreate(90, 20)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, $text, $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

This code in working and converting my text to image.

**Update:**

How can I set background Image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the font used by ImageString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423192/change-the-font-used-by-imagestring)

Comment: I checked '$font_width = imagefontwidth(36);' but not working.Font size still remain same..

Comment: I change '$font = 'fonts/arial.ttf'' to '$font = 'fonts/Arial.ttf';' and it work....

Answer (score 1):

The font size is the second parameter for [`imagestring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php), it has sizes 1-5. So, e.g.:

```
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, $text, $text_color); // size 1

imagestring($im, 2, 5, 5, $text, $text_color); // size 2

// etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $name="vikram";
    header( "Content-type: image/png" );
    $my_img = imagecreate( 400, 300 );
    $background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255,255, 255 );
    $text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 120, 120, 120);
    $font='arial.ttf';
    imagettftext($my_img,40,5,100,200,$text_colour,$font,$name); 
    imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );   
    imagepng('vikram.png');
    imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
    imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
    imagecolordeallocate( $background );
    imagedestroy( $my_img );
```